# Networkx multiple attributes on nodes for multiple labels on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, nodes, networkx

I am working on a recommendation system that is using [formal concept analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis) to find the nearest similar client in a network. To create the formal concepts I am using pandas, for the networks networkx and for plotting matplotlib ie everything in Python 3.

My problem is that I want to represent on a graph the 2 types of attributes that have each node : names of clients and movies for instance. To give a quick example : node 1 : "names" -> ["Bob","John"] ; "movies" -> ["Jaws"].
The "names" and "movies" are coded as attributes to nodes. To continue the example :

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2])
G.add_edge(1,2)    
G.node[1]['names']=["Bob","John"]
G.node[1]['movies']=["Jaws"]
```

Unfortunately, after long hours to search how to put 2 types of label on each node of the graph, I didn't find the answer. Here is what I think I should use but I don't know how to interact with matplotlib or networkx to do the double labelling :

```
node_labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G,"names")
node_labels2 = nx.get_node_attributes(G,"movies")
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,labels = ?)
```

Another important aspect of the problem is to put the "movies" on top of the node, and the "names" under the node as shown in the image below.

[An image of the type of graph I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tpIA.png)

Thank you a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your network what does a node represent and what does an edge represent? Does each node represent a user and each edge similar taste between two users? I think you should clarify that because from your question it seems you have not.

Comment: To be honest I didn't write it to keep the topic about programming only but here is the idea:
With the formal concept analysis you create formal concepts that are links between users and films. The bottom of the graph (or tree) represents the starting point of the objects (ie "names" here). After, the top of the graph is the starting point of the attributes (ie "movies" here). In term of objects, the graph is oriented for bottom to top.

Comment: For instance, with the image I gave: Ashley saw the movies that Bob, Paul, Jordan and Gabby saw. But in addition to all of them she saw Jaws. On the other hand, in term of attributes, the graph is oriented from top to bottom. With the same example: Rambo was seen by Paul, Jordan, Ashley and John.
This graph is kind of a simplification of the complete graph that you may think of, the one with each node representing multiples users and the movies they saw. Therefore, the nodes represent both users and movies and their edges are just links oriented in both directions. I hope I made it clearer :)

Comment: No you did not :) . The thing is that the pic you show is more like a tree than a graph. In a graph an edge is not just a link. It represents something and you can add a weight to that. For example take Bob, Paul and Jordan. Bob and Paul share 5 movies and Bob and Jordan share 2. This could be a graph with 3 nodes and 2 edges (B,P,weight=5) and (B,J,weight=2). The weights are not needed but you can use them to add more information to the graph.The labels you are trying to use are just strings and are just used to identify the nodes from one another. Most people use integers for that.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I need to find trees visualization tool. I looked it up a little and I found a python [library](https://github.com/xflr6/concepts) similar to what I want and it uses graphviz library. I'm gonna look more into depth there. Thank you for your help.